# Namespace recognition in edit for php

Tags: php, eclipse, drupal, namespaces

Namespace recognition in edit for php.

I am using the sublime text editor and aware of eclipse editor. Wanted to know if namespace recognition is available in this editor of php.

Comment: I think sublime text editor is not a IDE and can't recognize it.

Comment: I haven't use sublime a while now but maybe you can add the package: SublimePHPCompanion looks like is something you want for this: https://github.com/erichard/SublimePHPCompanion

Answer (score 1):

there are couple of packages which can provide namespace recognition

https://github.com/erichard/SublimePHPCompanion

https://github.com/gl3n/sublime-php-namespace